# I'am getting an error "at-rule or selector expected"?

Tags: lightning-web-components, css

HTML->

```
 <template>
            <div class="tile" style={backgroundImageStyle}>
                <p>{property.City__c}</p>
                <p>{property.Beds__c}-{property.Bath__c}</p>
                <p>{property.Price__c}</p>
            </div>
 </template>
```

JS->

```
import { LightningElement,api } from 'lwc';
   export default class LwcPropertyTile extends LightningElement {
        @api property;

        get backgroundImageStyle() {
            return `background-image:url(${this.property.Thumbnail__c})`;
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see an import statement in the JS file. Add below in the first line of js

```
import { LightningElement, api} from 'lwc';
```

If that doesn't solve, turn off the HTML > Validate:Styles in the VS code settings.

Comment: Disabling worked for me; thanks! P.S. Also note that using vue-html instead of HTML works well for LWC development.